# Speed of a Spider Tank?

Tags: science-fiction, vehicles, mechs

Disregarding all the impracticalities of a legged vehicle, assuming one was created, how fast would it be? I know there are a ton of variables, so I’m just looking for a ballpark estimate for a vehicle designed for scouting missions, similar to a Bradley or Striker.

The Stryker weighs 19 tons, the Bradley about 28 tons. The Stryker has a top speed of 60mph, the Bradley 40mph. I believe both can cover open ground at about the same speed of around 30–35mph.

How would a Spider Tank (vehicle with 4–8 legs) of comparable size perform? Would the number of legs make a difference? Is it even possible to do a back of the envelope calculation for something like this?

Comment: Well worth a watch for answerers: [The flick-flack spider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RerXsbuJ1S4) (Youtube video 1.13 long, apologies for the annoying commentary). Does this sort of motion fit within the range of acceptable behaviours of your tank Ryan?

Comment: For a vehicle weighing in excess of 20 tons? Probably not! 

Comment: I was going to mention something similar to a A new normal, with this robot spider bit likely impossible for tank, still interesting though https://www.mirror.co.uk/tech/terrifying-robot-spider-can-roll-12277544

Comment: I think something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftV2HeKPeBM) might be the only real world example even remotely in the same weight class. And even if you improve it to be capable of ten times the speed, it will still be uselessly slow.

Answer (score 2):

When moving on legs you (or whatever is using the legs) can't move faster than the speed with which the legs can be pushed back.

Considering that the legs are also supposed to sustain the load of the body and thus have to be bulky and not slender, I doubt you can sprint faster than 40 km/h. Sustained movement will be slower.

I got that figure by comparing the running speed of an elephant.

Comment: Sounds legit. 25mph top speed over open terrain is about what I was hoping for, with a walking pace of about 10mph.

Comment: I would never have thought to estimate this by looking at the running speeds of extant animals, but it kinda makes sense in a weird way...

Answer (score 2):

What kind of technology would be available in your story? 
The main constraints would be power and properties of the materials.
Assuming a power generator source of suitable power and endurance and sufficiently strong materials you could have a leaping vehicle capable of speeds much higher than 40km/h. It would be able to walk at normal speeds but when needed sprint in leaps in a similar way that a cheetah does.
Most likely it would be an unmanned vehicle. Sitting inside a 20 ton leaping vehicle would soon incapacitate humans. It could have an inner suspended cell with dampeners though but that would be a detriment in weight and space.

The extra legs would be a bonus on uneven ground. If one of the legs does not manage to gain proper grip then the next one most likely will. 
Kinda what happens with the RHex:
[RHex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISznqY3kESI)

Comment: Thinking either a coal dust turbine or hydrogen fuel cells driving hydraulically-powered legs. This is for a mid-19th century steampunk story, so some level of handwavium is acceptable. This is definitely not hard science fiction.